# Use of undefined constant XML_PI_NODE in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting this error in php7.2. I'm using symfony4.

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant XML_PI_NODE - assumed 'XML_PI_NODE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

This is the error line.

```
in var/cache/dev/ContainerIZRQnYa/getSerializerService.php (line 55)
return $this->services['serializer'] = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer([0 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\JsonSerializableNormalizer(), 1 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer(), 2 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ConstraintViolationListNormalizer(), 3 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateIntervalNormalizer(), 4 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DataUriNormalizer(), 5 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer(), 6 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer($a, new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\MetadataAwareNameConverter($a), new \Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor(false, false, new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\ArrayAdapter(0, false)), NULL, new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\ClassDiscriminatorFromClassMetadata($a))], [0 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder(), 1 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder(), 2 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\YamlEncoder(), 3 => new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\CsvEncoder()]);
```

I already cleared cache and all permission has setted before.
What should i do?

Comment: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/869

Comment: php 7-2xml is already installed on my server, tried that before.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, I'd installed PHP XML using

`sudo apt install php7.4-xml`

but was still getting it. It went away after I ran:

`install zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev`

Comment: `sudo apt install php-xml` was enough for my php8.1.2 installation under ubuntu jammy (22.04), thanks

Comment: `sudo apt install phpX.X-xml `
Should be enough, don't need to install zlib1g. If it's not fixed try 
    `sudo a2dismod phpX.X`
    `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
    `sudo a2enmod php X.X `
    `sudo systemctl restart apache2`