# 'Undefined constant "XML_PI_NODE"' on php8 with php-xml / php8.0-xml installed on Symfony

Tags: symfony

It is a duplicate issue of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047824/use-of-undefined-constant-xml-pi-node-in-symfony-4)

I have followed the instruction, but id did not solved the issue.

I have installed php8.0, php-xml, php8.0-xml and composer (using install script), then ran `composer install` successfuly.

On my webapp's root, there is a HTTP 500 error: `Undefined constant "XML_PI_NODE"`

You can see more log at http://1ib.re

I am on a Debian 10 Buster server.

Thank you for your help \o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find solution.
Solved after reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install php-xml

Hope it will solve you problem.

Comment: I have already installed such package.

I had to reinstall the Debian distro, for an other reason. I had not this problem this time.